# how to make groupby bar plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to make a barplot from the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sales={'Apple':[50, 60, 40, 55],
    'Orange': [40, 25, 35, 60],
   'Cucumber': [10, 30, 40, 15],
   'Banana': [70, 60, 40, 50],
   'Peach':[10, 30, 40, 20],
   'Melon': [5, 20, 70, 10],
   'Berries': [30, 40, 50, 60]}

data=pd.DataFrame(sales, index=['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'])
```

I define a function as below:

```
def bar_plots(df, bar_width, alpha=0.3, colors=None ):
    indx=np.arange(df.shape[1])
    for colm, idx, colr in zip(df.columns, indx, colors):
        plt.bar([p+(bar_width*idx) for p in indx ], df[colm], alpha, colr, label=colm )
    plt.xlabel('Quarters')
    plt.ylabel('Sales')
    plt.xticks(index + (bar_width*(len(indx))) / (len(indx)+1), ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'))
```

I am getting the following error when I call the function:

```
bar_plots(data, 0.3, alpha=0.3, colors=['r','orange','g','y','coral','lime','b'] )



AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

I don't know where I am making mistake and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `plot(kind='bar')`

```
data.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: data.plot(kind='bar')]

Comment: @nimrodz-thanks for the answer.  Although pandas and seaborn can do the easier barplot, I was interested to do it in matplotlib for teaching